Integer to date conversion within Databricks
I have date in the String format 20240107193154 within databricks dataframe, I want to convert this into YYY-MM-DD:HH:MM:SS datetime format within Pyspark .
I have tried using unixtimestmp but no luck.

We'll need 2 functions to achieve your goal:

to_timestamp
date_format

Here's an example of how we might achieve this:
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# example data
data = [
  ['a', '20240104193154'],
  ['b', '20240105193154'],
  ['c', '20240106193154'],
  ['d', '20240107193154'],
  ['e', '20240108193154'],
  ['f', '20240109193154']]

schema = StructType([
  StructField("Event", StringType(), True),
  StructField("StringTimeStamp", StringType(), True)
])

# create dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

# F.to_timestamp converts the string format to a timestamp
# F.date_format converts the timestamp to desired string format
(
  df
  .withColumn('Timestamp',F.to_timestamp(F.col('StringTimeStamp'),'yyyyMMddHHmmss'))
  .withColumn('FormattedString',F.date_format(F.col('Timestamp'),'yyyy-MM-dd:hh:mm:ss'))
).show()

We can see the results:
+-----+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|Event|StringTimeStamp|          Timestamp|    FormattedString|
+-----+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    a| 20240104193154|2024-01-04 19:31:54|2024-01-04:07:31:54|
|    b| 20240105193154|2024-01-05 19:31:54|2024-01-05:07:31:54|
|    c| 20240106193154|2024-01-06 19:31:54|2024-01-06:07:31:54|
|    d| 20240107193154|2024-01-07 19:31:54|2024-01-07:07:31:54|
|    e| 20240108193154|2024-01-08 19:31:54|2024-01-08:07:31:54|
|    f| 20240109193154|2024-01-09 19:31:54|2024-01-09:07:31:54|
+-----+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+

